# Cucumber: undefined scenario/steps when running a bunch of test with tags (annotations) using POM.xml

Tags: selenium, cucumber, pom.xml

I am facing a problem when executing cucumber scripts having tags using POM.XML. I wish to run it without a runner class.

When I use the running class, the scripts run well and I get the below output.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=51160:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/umeshanand/Documents/Selenium/Frameworks/FW.BDD/target/test-classes:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.2/cucumber-java-1.2.2.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.7.1/selenium-java-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/3.7.1/selenium-api-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.7.1/selenium-chrome-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/3.7.1/selenium-edge-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.7.1/selenium-firefox-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/3.7.1/selenium-ie-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-opera-driver/3.7.1/selenium-opera-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.7.1/selenium-remote-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/3.7.1/selenium-safari-driver-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/3.7.1/selenium-support-3.7.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.7.5/byte-buddy-1.7.5.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.18/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.2/cucumber-core-1.2.2.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-html/0.2.3/cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.3/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin-2.12.2.jar:/Users/umeshanand/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-junit/1.2.2/cucumber-junit-1.2.2.jar:test/java/.:src/test/java/stepDefs" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 runner.runnertest
objc[976]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x102c0d4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10352b4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launch browser
 open google
enter powercor
validate results
Launch browser
 open google
enter powercor
validate results
Launch browser
 open google
enter powercor
validate results

3 Scenarios (3 passed)
12 Steps (12 passed)
0m0.125s
```

When I execute using a POM.XML, I get the below message (please note I am trying to execute one of the three tags @google1, @google2, @google3)

```
 --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default) @ FW_BDD ---
Feature: First test to launch google

  @google1
  Scenario: Launch Google and search something       # features/googlenew.feature:4
    Given I open Chrome browser
    And user open google
    When user enter powercor in textbox
    Then search results should should poercor.com.au

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I open Chrome browser$")
public void i_open_Chrome_browser() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Given("^user open google$")
public void user_open_google() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^user enter powercor in textbox$")
public void user_enter_powercor_in_textbox() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^search results should should poercor\\.com\\.au$")
public void search_results_should_should_poercor_com_au() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}


Process finished with exit code 1

Execution happens through below :
clean install -DtagArg=@google1
```

POM.XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FW_BDD</groupId>
    <artifactId>FW_BDD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <tagArg>~@ignore</tagArg>
        <format>pretty</format>


    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>test/java/.</additionalClasspathElement>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/stepDefs</additionalClasspathElement>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>test/java/.</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>

                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <!--<includes>
                        <include>**/*test.java</include>
                    </includes>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                            <mainClass>cucumber.api.cli.Main</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--plugin</argument>
                                <argument>junit:reports/junit.xml</argument>
                                <argument>--plugin</argument>
                                <argument>json:reports/json.json</argument>
                                <argument>--plugin</argument>
                                <argument>html:reports/</argument>
                                <argument>--plugin</argument>
                                <argument>pretty</argument>
                                <argument>--strict</argument>
                                <argument>--glue</argument>
                                <argument>target/test-classes</argument>
                                <argument>target/test-classes/.</argument>
                                <argument>--tags</argument>
                                <argument>~@ignore</argument>
                                <argument>--tags</argument>
                                <argument>${tagArg}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried using groovy over Java and things work very well. I use IntelliJ and am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the feature files and step definitions are in src/test/java/stepDefs ..... src/test/resources/features

Comment: Please add your runner class code also ?

Comment: Here you go ...

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        //features = {"src/test/resources/features/googlenew.features"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"stepDefs"},
        plugin = {"pretty:target/cucumber-pretty-report",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber.xml"}//,
        //tags={"@goldest1"}
)
public class runnertest {
}

Comment: I am not looking to use a runner class. I only wish to have feature files and step defs and execute thru POM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "--glue" argument is incorrect. This should be the full package name for the step definition classes instead of "target/test-classes". For example, if those classes are located in the "com.cucumber.steps" package, then the POM should look like:

```
<argument>--glue</argument>
<argument>com.cucumber.steps</argument>
...
<argument>src/test/resources/features</argument>
```

Comment: @ Andre, I tried changing the glue to 

<argument>--glue</argument>
<argument>stepDefs</argument>

However I get the below during execution

[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default) @ FW_BDD ---
Got no path to feature directory or feature file

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

Comment: My project dir structure is 

Step definitions at:

|-src
  |-test
    |-java
      |-stepDefs
        |-StepDefinitions.java

Feature files at:

|-src
  |-test
    |-resources
      |-features
        |-gogtest.feature

Comment: @uanand Have you tried to add as a last parameter `<argument>src/test/resources/features</argument>`? Would also be good if you could please share the content of feature file. Thanks.

Comment: @ Andre many thanks. It has started working. I added the below 2 in POM.XML 

<argument>--glue</argument>
                                <argument>stepDefs</argument>
                                <argument>src/test/resources/features</argument>

I have even tried tried removing the runner class and its working... Once again many thanks